# My Google Analytics goals shows 0 conversion?

Tags: google-tag-manager

My analytics goals show 0 conversions.

2 months ago, I set up 15 goals in Google Analytics. It is URL type of goals.

http://prntscr.com/pnmsn5

I configured GTA with all the tags and variables:

http://prntscr.com/pnmt1g
http://prntscr.com/pnmt70

My mailchimp list is growing because user subscribe or download my lead magnet. But I don't see the counter of goals raising:

http://prntscr.com/pnmtyx

Even when I open myself the "thank you" url, I can see the tags are fired but I don't see goal incrementing!?

http://prntscr.com/pnmurh

So I searched here and in Google but I couldn't find any solution. GTM say it become easier to manage tags, but it is very difficult to configure for me.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your screenshot, your success page is located at `/merci-telecharger-101-growth-hacks-pdf/`, with a trailing `/`. Your goal requires the page path to be equal to `/merci-telecharger-101-growth-hacks-pdf`, without the trailing `/`.

So the success URL does not match the criteria set for the goal. You can verify this, if you look at the content report, and look for the success URL page views. You need to adjust your goal settings to match the actual URL on your site.